# Is there any way to test ethereum application using real addresses by Metamask?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, react

I have an Ethereum app written using react + web3 and my contract code written using solidity. Can I test the app using real addresses [I used Rinkbey network] and my wallet Metamask?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You need to connect to your web3 app to your metamask wallet using metamask API. First, set the web3 provider to metamask's using

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
```

Then connect you account to the site using:

```
window.ethereum
.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts"})
.then( () => {
  // after logic
})
.catch( (err) => {
  // handle user rejection
});
```

Now you can use your metamask accounts to interact with your smart contracts.

Comment: I  set the provider by: const provider = new HDWalletProvider([my metmask secret words ], "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/5ad4d5f373164a45b154a683140487f4"); Is that correct ?

Comment: This is ok as well but then you are not using Metamask anymore as provider, just Infura node.